# Best practice to use ffaker gem to generate pseudo data in seed.rb file?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, faker, fake-repositories

After running rake db:seed, I get the following error: NameError: uninitialized constant Faker

gem file

```
gem 'ffaker'
```

seeds.rb file

```
10.times do
     Employee.create(
        email: Faker::Internet.email,
        password: Faker::Internen.password,
        fname: Faker::Name.first_name,
        lname: Faker::Name.last_name
      ) 
end
```

Is there something that I am missing? What if I wanted to add a custom range? Would I just use a definition block? Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `FFaker` namespace (not `Faker`).

Look at official examples [here](https://github.com/EmmanuelOga/ffaker).

Comment: you have got to be kidding me. I will off myself shortly after this. Thanks man for the quick help.